# Cap colour in IPL

Tags: cricket, indian-premier-league

If a player is the highest run scorer and at the same time is the highest wicket taker in IPL, which colour cap would he wear?

Comment: I think it is an award, both caps will be given to the player and the player can choose which one to wear, I don't have any supporting reference.

Comment: He can wear whichever cap he wants to wear. I am sorry, I don't really see any answerable question here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rules for Orange and Purple Caps in IPL](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2522/rules-for-orange-and-purple-caps-in-ipl)

Comment: @MaskedMan perhaps we should treat the question as "Is a player required to wear the orange or purple cap if they are entitled to them, and if so, which cap must they wear if they are required to wear both?" Well, I suppose they *could* wear both caps, but it would be a bit uncomfortable :-)

Answer (score 2):

I see two questions here:

> What caps would he be given if he's both the highest wicket taker and
>   the leading run scorer?

According to the rules, **both the caps would be awarded to the player,** after the respective innings in which he earned them.

> What cap would/should he wear if he's awarded both?

There isn't any rule which binds the player to the colour of the cap which he should be wearing. It is a personal choice for the player. (which is already addressed rightly in the comments under the question.)

[Helpful Post](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/2522/10319)